# R : Error expr did not evaluate to an object of length n

Tags: r

I create two functions with R this way :

```
 esp<-function(x) x*dexp(x,lambda)
```

then :

```
 esp2<-function(R) integrate(esp,0,R)
```

I can plot the first one, but when I try to plot the second one I get an error :

```
'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length n
```

With some research, I have to use sapply function, or vectorize function. But first, I don't know why, and secondly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `Vectorize` it because `curve` expects such a function for it to calculate the plotting data. It doesn't work because `integrate` outputs a complicated object. Therefore you need to isolate the relevant part of the output:

```
esp2 <- function(R) integrate(esp,0,R)$value
plot(Vectorize(esp2))
```

Comment: It works better with the $value, but I don't know exactly its purpose.

Comment: @Saroupille `integrate` returns more than just the calculated integral; it also returns an estimate of the error, and any diagnostic messages if it failed. All of this is wrapped up in a list. The `$value` extracts just the value of the integral.